# Can we build a react native app without using expo and typescript?

Tags: react-native

When I run **npx create-react-native-app appName** or **npx react-native init appName**, it either creates an expo in package.json or an App.tsx. Because of the numerous responses, I will rename the file *App.tsx* to *App.js*, but this will result in an error.

I'd like to construct a react native app without using expo or typescript.

Comment: if you want to take a build for ios and android  then you should go with xcode and android studio respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new project with the specific version of react-native.
From the 0.71 version typescript is the default format.

To create project in specific version you have to run command like this

```
npx react-native init demo --version 0.69.0
```